# Reset the position of a label after drag and drop

Tags: c#

I have a game being written in C# which has 4 disks that are represented by labels and 3 pegs that are also represented by labels. when I press the reset button I want the disks to reset back to the first disk.
Can anyone help with how to do this?

```
namespace HanoiTowers1
{
/// <summary>
/// This form lets the user play a game of HanoiTowers.
/// 4 labels representing disks are shown on the first of three poles. It is possible 
/// to drag a disk from one pole to another. The rules for a valid move are that
/// a bigger disk cannot be dropped on top of a smaller one. The aim of the game
/// is to move the stack of disks to another pole one disk at a time.
/// Moves made by Dragging are recorder as lines of text in a textBox
/// It is possible to reset the disks to their original position
/// It is also possible to replay the moves stored in the textbox
/// either by stepping through them - the [Step] button
/// or from a timer - started by the [Animate] button
/// </summary>
public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private Disk[,] disks = new Disk[3,4];
    //array of possible positions of disks over the 3 poles and four levels
    //the array keeps track of where the labels representing the disks are
    //the Disk class stores the pole and level of a label representing the disk
    //as well as an object refrence to the label

    private int targetPole = 0;
    //used to communicate between DragDrop which identifies the pole being dropped on
    //and the MouseDown method for the "disks" which will move a "disk" to a new
    //pole after DragDrop is completed

    private int animateLine = 0;
    //used to say which line in a list of moves is the current move

    private bool isStepping = false;
    //if moves are being made from a list, not by drag and drop
    //isStepping is used to prevent recording the moves made

    private int MoveCount = 0; //count of moves made in a game

    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label Disk4;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label Disk3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label Disk2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label Pole2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label Pole1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label Pole3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label Disk1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    private System.Timers.Timer timer1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnReset;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnAnimate;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnStep;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblMoves;
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        //
        // Required for Windows Form Designer support
        //
        InitializeComponent();

        //
        // TODO: Add any constructor code after InitializeComponent call
        //
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        if( disposing )
        {
            if (components != null) 
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose( disposing );
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.Disk4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.Disk3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.Disk2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.Disk1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.btnReset = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.Pole2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.Pole1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.Pole3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.btnAnimate = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
        this.btnStep = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.lblMoves = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)         (this.timer1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(120, 240);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(584, 48);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // Disk4
        // 
        this.Disk4.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
        this.Disk4.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.Disk4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(157, 216);
        this.Disk4.Name = "Disk4";
        this.Disk4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(144, 24);
        this.Disk4.TabIndex = 5;
        this.Disk4.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Disk1_Click);
        this.Disk4.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Disk1_MouseDown);
        // 
        // Disk3
        // 
        this.Disk3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
        this.Disk3.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.Disk3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(173, 192);
        this.Disk3.Name = "Disk3";
        this.Disk3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(112, 24);
        this.Disk3.TabIndex = 6;
        this.Disk3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Disk1_Click);
        this.Disk3.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Disk1_MouseDown);
        // 
        // Disk2
        // 
        this.Disk2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
        this.Disk2.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.Disk2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(189, 168);
        this.Disk2.Name = "Disk2";
        this.Disk2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 24);
        this.Disk2.TabIndex = 7;
        this.Disk2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Disk1_Click);
        this.Disk2.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Disk1_MouseDown);
        // 
        // Disk1
        // 
        this.Disk1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
        this.Disk1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.Disk1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(205, 144);
        this.Disk1.Name = "Disk1";
        this.Disk1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 24);
        this.Disk1.TabIndex = 8;
        this.Disk1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Disk1_Click);
        this.Disk1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Disk1_MouseDown);
        // 
        // btnReset
        // 
        this.btnReset.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 16);
        this.btnReset.Name = "btnReset";
        this.btnReset.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 32);
        this.btnReset.TabIndex = 9;
        this.btnReset.Text = "Reset";
        this.btnReset.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnReset_Click);
        // 
        // Pole2
        // 
        this.Pole2.AllowDrop = true;
        this.Pole2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))));
        this.Pole2.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.Pole2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(400, 112);
        this.Pole2.Name = "Pole2";
        this.Pole2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 144);
        this.Pole2.TabIndex = 10;
        this.Pole2.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.Pole1_DragDrop);
        this.Pole2.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.Pole2_DragEnter);
        // 
        // Pole1
        // 
        this.Pole1.AllowDrop = true;
        this.Pole1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))));
        this.Pole1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.Pole1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(216, 112);
        this.Pole1.Name = "Pole1";
        this.Pole1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 144);
        this.Pole1.TabIndex = 11;
        this.Pole1.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.Pole1_DragDrop);
        this.Pole1.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.Pole2_DragEnter);
        // 
        // Pole3
        // 
        this.Pole3.AllowDrop = true;
        this.Pole3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))));
        this.Pole3.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.Pole3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(576, 112);
        this.Pole3.Name = "Pole3";
        this.Pole3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 144);
        this.Pole3.TabIndex = 13;
        this.Pole3.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.Pole1_DragDrop);
        this.Pole3.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.Pole2_DragEnter);
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(280, 16);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(64, 40);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 14;
        this.label1.Text = "Moves:";
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(728, 16);
        this.textBox1.Multiline = true;
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(136, 280);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 15;
        // 
        // btnAnimate
        // 
        this.btnAnimate.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 112);
        this.btnAnimate.Name = "btnAnimate";
        this.btnAnimate.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 32);
        this.btnAnimate.TabIndex = 16;
        this.btnAnimate.Text = "Animate";
        this.btnAnimate.Visible = false;
        this.btnAnimate.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnAnimate_Click);
        // 
        // timer1
        // 
        this.timer1.Interval = 500D;
        this.timer1.SynchronizingObject = this;
        this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Elapsed);
        // 
        // btnStep
        // 
        this.btnStep.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 64);
        this.btnStep.Name = "btnStep";
        this.btnStep.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 32);
        this.btnStep.TabIndex = 17;
        this.btnStep.Text = "Step";
        this.btnStep.Visible = false;
        this.btnStep.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnStep_Click);
        // 
        // lblMoves
        // 
        this.lblMoves.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
        this.lblMoves.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(368, 16);
        this.lblMoves.Name = "lblMoves";
        this.lblMoves.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 24);
        this.lblMoves.TabIndex = 18;
        this.lblMoves.Text = "0";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(8, 19);
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(888, 365);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lblMoves);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnStep);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnAnimate);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnReset);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Disk1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Disk2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Disk3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Disk4);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Pole1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Pole2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Pole3);
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Basic version of Hanoi Towers";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.timer1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() 
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    //put all four disks back in order on first pole
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        MoveCount = 0;
        lblMoves.Text = MoveCount.ToString();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    //create Disk objects matching the "Disk" labels on the first pole
    {
        disks[0,3] = new Disk(Disk1,1,4);
        disks[0,2] = new Disk(Disk2,1,3);
        disks[0,1] = new Disk(Disk3,1,2);
        disks[0,0] = new Disk(Disk4,1,1);
    }

    private bool DropOnPole(int oldPole, int oldLevel, int newPole)
    //Move a disk from its current position to the next available position
    //on the new pole and check that the move is valid
    {
        int newLevel;
        oldPole--;
        oldLevel--;
        newPole--;

        if (disks[newPole, 3] != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Move - pole is full");
            return false;
        }
        else if (disks[oldPole, oldLevel] == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Move - no disk at start point");
            return false;
        }

        if (oldLevel < 3)
        {
            if (disks[oldPole, oldLevel +1 ] != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Move - can only move top disk");
                return false;
            }
        }

        newLevel = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (disks[newPole,i] == null)
            {
                newLevel = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (newLevel > 0) 
        {
            if ( disks[oldPole, oldLevel].thisDisk.Width > disks[newPole,newLevel - 1].thisDisk.Width)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Move - cannot drop bigger disk on smaller");
                return false;
            }
        }

        disks[newPole, newLevel] = disks[oldPole, oldLevel];
        disks[oldPole, oldLevel] = null;
        disks[newPole, newLevel].Move(newPole+1, newLevel+1);
        if (!isStepping)
        {
            string theMove = disks[newPole, newLevel].thisDisk.Name + ','
                + (newPole +1).ToString() + ',' + (newLevel+1).ToString() +"\r\n";
            textBox1.AppendText(theMove);
            MoveCount++;
            lblMoves.Text = MoveCount.ToString();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void Disk1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void getPoleAndLevel( out int pole, out int level, Label thislabel)
    //given an object reference to the label representing a disk
    //find its position in the 3x4 disks array of possible positions
    {
        pole = -1;
        level = -1;
        for (int ipole = 0; ipole < 3; ipole++)
        {
            for (int jlevel = 0; jlevel < 4; jlevel++)
            {
                if (disks[ipole,jlevel] != null)
                {
                    if (disks[ipole,jlevel].thisDisk == thislabel) 
                    {
                        pole = ipole + 1;
                        level = jlevel + 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (pole > -1) break;
        }
    }

    private void Disk1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Label alabel = (sender as Label);
        int pole, level;
        getPoleAndLevel( out pole, out level, alabel);

        DragDropEffects result = alabel.DoDragDrop(alabel,DragDropEffects.All);
        if (result != DragDropEffects.None)
        {
            DropOnPole(pole, level, targetPole);
        }
    }

    private void Pole2_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
    //change the cursor to show dropping is allowed
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
    }

    private void Pole1_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
    //when a drop happens store the information about which pole was
    //dropped on in the global variable targetPole
    {
        Label alabel = (sender as Label);
        if (alabel == Pole1) targetPole = 1;
        else if (alabel == Pole2) targetPole = 2;
        else if (alabel == Pole3) targetPole = 3;
    }

    private Label getDisk(string DiskName)
    //given a string with the .Name property of a disk
    //return a reference to that disk assuming that only valid names are passed
    {

        if (DiskName == "Disk1")
        {
            return Disk1;
        }
        else if (DiskName == "Disk2")
        {
            return Disk2;
        }
        else if (DiskName == "Disk3")
        {
            return Disk3;
        }
        else if (DiskName == "Disk4")
        {
            return Disk4;
        }
        else return Disk4;
    }

    private void btnAnimate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    //turn the timer on to begin animation of the moves stored in the textbox
    {

    }

    private void btnStep_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    //repeat of the moves stored in the textbox one move at a time
    {
        if (animateLine >= textBox1.Lines.Length-1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Last available move has been completed");
            return;
        }
        MakeNextMove();
    }

    private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    //repeat one of the moves stored in the textbox each time the timer fires
    {
        if (!MakeNextMove())
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private bool MakeNextMove()
    //repeat one of the moves stored in the textbox
    {
        int oldPole, oldLevel, newPole;
        bool MoveOK = false;
        string aMove = textBox1.Lines[animateLine];
        string[] parts = aMove.Split(',');
        Label aDisk = getDisk(parts[0]);
        newPole = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]);
        getPoleAndLevel( out oldPole, out oldLevel, aDisk);
        isStepping = true; //will prevent adding more moves to the textbox from the replay
        MoveOK = DropOnPole(oldPole, oldLevel, newPole);
        isStepping = false;

        if (!MoveOK)
        {
            return false;
        }

        animateLine++;
        if (animateLine >= textBox1.Lines.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
/* sample set of text moves
```

Disk1,2,1
Disk2,3,1
Disk1,3,2
Disk3,2,1
Disk1,1,2
Disk2,2,2
Disk1,2,3
*/

Thanks
Ryan

Comment: You should share some of your code and what you have attempted so far. Is this webforms, winforms, another thing? Please, tag your question accordingly and take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We can help you with specific technical problems you are having, but we can't write your entire game for you.

Comment: Sorry about that. It is a Windows Form. I am using a starter project provided from someone else. I have changed the initial post to include all my code.

Comment: Do your Disks have a location and a name, variables?? Because in Winforms you can get the Location directly in the form window.. Just change the locations accordingly.. Once you have the location of the first Disk just offset the others to match..

Comment: The Disks positions are stored in arrays I believe.

Comment: I have decided that the way I would do it is to just recreate the form and close the previous version

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
objectA.Location = new Point((int)A.position, objectA.Location.Y);
```

Then just offset the other Disks to reset their locations..